# libGL error running google-chrome on server 18.04.1

Tags: google-chrome

I installed google-chrome-stable on an Ubuntu 18.04.1 server like this:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

When I connect with ssh -X and run google chrome I receive libGL errors as below.

```
$ google-chrome
libGL error: failed to open drm device: Permission denied
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
```

Looking in `/dev`, there is no drm, instead I have a `dri` folder. Google chrome opens but I'm wondering why I have such errors? Is this to be expected?